# Syntax error creating MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

Perhaps I'm just too used to Postgres but why am I getting this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '{   id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,     email varchar(100) not null,
>     primary key(id' at line 1

when I run this?

```
create table `users`{
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(100) not null,
    primary key(id)
};
```

Comment: Use parentheses `CREATE TABLE Users ( ... )` not braces `CREATE TABLE Users { ... }`.

Comment: Use () at the place of {}

Comment: That syntax isn't valid for Postgres either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parenthesis (normal brackets) `()` not braces:

```
create table `users` (
    id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email varchar(100) not null,
    primary key(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct syntax is :

CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
  );

check it out here for your version:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/creating-tables.html